# Trying to retrieve messages from Telegram group using Telethon and receiving error 'Cannot find any entity corresponding to 'test chat'

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, openai-api

I am trying to send messages retrieved from a channel on Telegram to chatgpt but when I run the code i keep getting this error :
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "GTT - Analysis & Signals" I have removed api id and hash.

```
import openai
import pandas as pd
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import configparser
import datetime

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('telethon.config')


teleapi_id = 'telegramapi_id here'
teleapi_hash = 'telegramapihash_here'





client = TelegramClient('none', teleapi_id, teleapi_hash)


#for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
#  if dialog.is_channel:
#      print(f'{dialog.id}:{dialog.title}')

df = pd.DataFrame()

chats = ['GTT - Analysis & Signals']

for chat in chats:
    with TelegramClient('test', teleapi_id, teleapi_hash) as client:
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date.today() , reverse=False):
            print(message)
            data = { "group" : chat, "sender" : message.sender_id, "text" : message.text, "date" : message.date}

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1])
            df = df.append(temp_df)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)

df.to_excel("C:TelegramCopier.xlsx".format(datetime.date.today()), index=False)
```

I tried using this code to load the cache because i believe the problem is something along the lines of that the cache is not loaded with the chat name or something but when i run that code i get this error :

```
for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
  if dialog.is_channel:
      print(f'{dialog.id}:{dialog.title}')
```

ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected

Comment: You can't get chats by their name. Only by their, user id and username, or using their respective InputPeer objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `connect()` before you can send requests to Telegram (such as the requests used by `iter_dialogs()`. [Telethon's documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/) shows how to do it:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
       if dialog.is_channel:
           print(f'{dialog.id}:{dialog.title}')
```